# Como posso pegar informações usando laravel com join encadeado?

Tags: laravel, query, laravel-eloquent

Tenho 3 camadas de entidades, Das quais só quero o terceiro objeto. porem com base na informação dos 2 primeiros.

Por exemplo, tenho fabrica que fabrica carros e cada carro tem um tipo de roda. Quero todas as rodas fabricadas por uma fabrica.

Não sei como fazer isto usando eloquent, A unica ideia que tive foi fazer vários hasMany para pegar estes dados. mas temo que não seja a forma mais eficiente pois acabarei pegando dados que não serão usados.

### Eu tentei isto mas não funcionou bem como queria.

```
DB::raw('select results from hectars h,consultas c,results r where h.id_fazendeiro=? and h.id=c.id_hectar and c.id = r.id_consulta',[$id]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Voce pode usar o método select() para puxar apenas as informações que voce quer, e o método join() para atrelar sua query com outra tabela.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#joins

Comment: Não é bem isto que desejo. Está mais para encadear varios objetos. Em tenho a informação do pai, e quero todos os fulhos.

Answer (score -3):

TabelaFabricas::join(tabelacarros, tabela carros.tabelafabrica_id, =, tabelafábricas.id)->join(tabelarodas, tabelarodas.tabelacarros_id, =, tabela carros.id)->select(tabelarodas.*)->where(tabelafabricas.id,colocaoiddafabricaaqui)->get()

A estrutura é essa. Fiz no celular, precisa colocar os nomes certinhos das tabelas.